# Sentence Transformation: not as ...as

Tags: prepositions, adverbs, nouns, negation

> This type of vinyl is no substitute for leather.

If I rewrite the given sentence as

> This type of vinyl is not as good substitution as  leather.

would it be correct?

Comment: Not exactly. You would say, "This type of vinyl is not *a* good substitute *for* leather." Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

It wasn't exactly clear what you were supposed to do with the "given sentence", but from the subject line

> **Sentence Transformation: not as …as**

a deduction might be made that you needed to transform

> "This type of vinyl is no substitute for leather."

*using the "not as... as" structure*.  If so, then the resulting sentence might be

> "This type of vinyl is **not as** good **as** leather."

There is no need to retain the word "substitution".

Answer (score 2):

> *This type of vinyl is not as good substitution as  leather. (ungrammatical)

This sentence is very nearly correct. One small change we would want to make is to use the word *substitute* instead of *substitution*. The noun *substitute* normally refers to the thing being substituted, but the noun *substitution* normally refers to the action of substituting. So if a manager changes one of the players in their team during a match and it works well we can say *That was a good substitution* meaning it was a good idea to change the players.

**Grammar**

If the Original Poster wants to say that vinyl is not as good as leather, then we need to leave out the word *substitute*, because leather it not a substitute for leather! We could say:

- Vinyl is not as good **a** material as leather.

In this construction we need an indefinite article between the adverb-adjective combination *as good* and the noun *material*.